# DateTime handling day+month

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have need to make a Week start and week end row with month names.

I have a calendar control where i set date.

And have this function:

```
public string DateToString(DateTime date)
    {
        string callback = "";
        return callback;
    }
```

I have problems figuring out how to handle week start and week end date and month.

I need string to look like< if end and beginning are different months:

29 July - 4. August, 2013

And the same month:

15 - 21. July, 2013 if the mounth is the same. Could you help me?

Comment: End and beginning in a single DateTime?

Comment: Wondering what does your posted function do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to pass two `DateTime` arguments to the method, then it makes more sense:

```
public static string DateToString(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd)
{
    if (dateStart.Year == dateEnd.Year && dateStart.Month == dateEnd.Month)
    { 
        return string.Format("{0} - {1}, {2}"
            , dateStart.ToString("dd")
            , dateEnd.ToString("dd MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            , dateStart.Year);
    }
    else if (dateStart.Year == dateEnd.Year)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} - {1}, {2}"
           , dateStart.ToString("dd MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           , dateEnd.ToString("dd MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           , dateStart.Year);
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Format("{0} - {1}"
               , dateStart.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
               , dateEnd.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Your sample data:

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2013, 07, 29);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2013, 08, 04);
Console.Write(DateToString(dt1, dt2));
dt1 = new DateTime(2013, 07, 15);
dt2 = new DateTime(2013, 07, 21);
Console.Write(DateToString(dt1, dt2));
```

Output:

```
29 July - 04 August, 2013:
15 - 21 July, 2013
```

---

So according to your comments you have a DateTime and you need to find the start and end of the week first. Then you want to build the string from these two dates:

```
public static DateTime StartOfWeek(DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
{
    int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
    if (diff < 0)
    {
        diff += 7;
    }

    return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
}
```

now you can use this method to find both dates:

```
var givenDate = new DateTime(2013, 08, 14);
var startWeekdate = StartOfWeek(givenDate, DayOfWeek.Monday);
var endWeekdate = startWeekdate.AddDays(6);
Console.WriteLine(DateToString(startWeekdate, endWeekdate));
```

prints:

```
12 - 18 August, 2013
```

Comment: So this is the main problem, i need to fing out the end and begin date according to the given Date.

That means, i give: 14.08.2013 adn it finds out the weeks beginning date (11.08.2013) and ending date (17.08.2013)

Comment: What culture are you using, when does your week begin?

Comment: Monday - is the beginning

Comment: @Cheese: Edited my answer. Please edit your question to clarify your requirement. It was not obvious in the first place. Then the downvotes will also be removed.